# Httpd docker stops after a number of days

Tags: apache, http, docker

I'm trying to run a small personal web server in docker using the httpd image in the docker store (https://store.docker.com/images/httpd).

However, it works ok in the beginning, but tends to simply stop a number of days later, and needs to be restarted using "docker start", and I've not found what is wrong. There are some advice on the net for a CentOS build, but I've not found any for the Docker Store image as-is.

Docker file is:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
LABEL maintainer "mats.ohrman@gmail.com"
COPY ./content/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY ./config/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./config/httpd-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Docker "build" cmd I used:

```
docker build -t matsohrman/web .
```

Docker "run" cmd I used:

```
docker run -dit --name web -p 80:80 matsohrman/web
```

Comment: Is there an application or code running as a part of the site?

Comment: No, static delivery of html, css and javascript files.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask for Apache httpd issues